# Travis build in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

I am trying to create automated testing for the backend of a MERN stack project I created. My directory structure is such that the `.travis.yml` file is in the root folder together with a backend folder and frontend folder and a `package.json` file.

In the `package.json` file, I have the test script as `cd backend && npm test` where the test script in the backend is `mocha test/*js`

However every time a build is triggered the build fails saying `mocha not found`

I have a feeling it has something to do with me trying to test in a subdirectory. Does anyone know how to resolve this or how to configure travis such that I can test in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding a custom script to `before_script` in my `.travis.yml`.

Right now, my current directory structure is as follows:

```
Project
   |-- backend  <-- Tests are located here
   |-- frontend
   |-- .travis.yml
   |-- package.json
   `-- Other misc files...
```

In order to make travis run tests in the subdirectory `Project/backend`, I needed to add the following to my `before_script`

```yaml
before_script:
  - cd backend
  - npm install mocha chai
```

After this, the tests worked like a charm.